# How to prevent onbeforeunload from being called when clicking submit button

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog

How can I prevent onbeforeunload from being called when clicking the submit button?

```
$(document).ready(function() 
 {
  $('input:text,input:checkbox,input:radio,textarea,select').one('change', function() 
  {
   //('BODY').attr('onbeforeunload',"return 'Leaving this page will cause any unsaved data to be lost.';");
   if(
   window.onbeforeunload = function() { return 'You have unsaved changes!'; }

  });

 });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't prevent the calling of unbeforeunload, but using a global flag variable, you can control whether it displays a warning.

in the document, add the script:

```
warn_on_unload = "You have unsaved changes!"
```

in the submit event, add:

```
warn_on_unload = "";
```

the definition of the event, change to:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return warn_on_unload; }
```

through `warn_on_unload`, you can now switch the warning message on or off at will.

Comment: How to add blur, keypress in this 
 $('input:text,input:checkbox,input:radio,textarea,select').one('change', function()

Comment: It's a different issue, you best open a new question for that.

Comment: No need for a flag, you can use window.unbeforeunload as the flag.  Assign the function to window.unbeforeunload in the change event, and assign null to the object in the submit event.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the final code:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    var warn_on_unload="";
    $('input:text,input:checkbox,input:radio,textarea,select').one('change', function() 
    {
        warn_on_unload = "Leaving this page will cause any unsaved data to be lost.";

        $('#submit').click(function(e) { 
            warn_on_unload = "";}); 

            window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
            if(warn_on_unload != ''){
                return warn_on_unload;
            }   
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use `.on()` to bind onbeforeunload and then use `.off()` to unbind it in form submission, short and sweet

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
        return "You have unsaved changes!";
    });
    $(document).on("submit", "form", function(event){
        $(window).off('beforeunload');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Modified it : now ignores form submission

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var warn_on_unload = "";
$('input:text,textarea').on('change', function () {
    warn_on_unload = "Leaving this page will cause any unsaved data to be lost.";
    $("form").submit(function () {
        warn_on_unload = "";
    });
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        if (warn_on_unload != '') {
            return warn_on_unload;
        }
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to disable Onbeforeunload Event on submit button.
So here an example code

```
document.getElementById('sub').onsubmit = function(e) {
 window.onbeforeunload = null;
 return true;
}
```

But if you want to monitors forms changes and alerts(confirmation Box) the user before leaving the page, Then I'll suggest you to you Plugin here is one jquery plugin that do exactly what i have written https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms

**The Plugin Monitior Your forms changes and alert before leaving the Page**

***The Best Part "It will not dispaly the alert Box when you click on Submit Button" OR You Submit your Form***

Example Code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.dirtyforms/2.0.0-beta00006/jquery.dirtyforms.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#form_verify').dirtyForms();
    })
  </script>

  <title></title>
 <body>
<form id="form_verify" action="a.php" method="POST">
    Firt Name <input type="text">
    Last Name <input type="file">
    <input type="submit">   
</form>
```

Comment: It DOES display the alertbox when you click the submit button. :-(